# Kafka Streams exactly_once_v2 produce duplicates after application restart

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, exactly-once

Please, we have kafka streams application with processing_quarantee=exactly_once_v2.

Kafka version: 3.2.0

Kafka Streams version: 3.0.1

Confluent version 7.0.1

Another configurations necessary for exactly once processing are also set:

**Producer:**

enable.idempotent=true

acks=all

**Consumer:**

isolation.level=read_committed

But when my application crashed and I restart it, **duplicates are produced to target topic**.

I notice that after restart new transactional.id is created so I try to configure transactional.id in code (lets say transactional.id=my-app) to keep same transactional ID across application restarts. But then I found this in log:

```
2023-01-11 19:30:42.791  WARN 31299 --- [           main] org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig   : Unexpected user-specified producer config: transactional.id found. processing.guarantee is set to exactly_once_v2. Hence, User setting (my-app) will be ignored and the Streams default setting (<appId>-<generatedSuffix>) will be used
```

Did I miss something?

I though the problem is that after every restart new transactional.id is created so we cannot start where we end before application failed.
But then why exactly_once_v2 doesn't allow to change transactional.id.

Has anyone experience with exactly_once_v2?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Streams manages `transactional.id` internally, and for eos_v2 it's expected that new `transactional.id`s are created (cf [KIP-447](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-447%3A+Producer+scalability+for+exactly+once+semantics) for details).

I am not aware of a correctness issues with regard to eos_v2 in 3.0.1 from top of my head. Did you check Kafka Jiras?

> But when my application crashed and I restart it, duplicates are produced to target topic.

Can you elaborate a little bit more? How do you verify this? Is the downstream consumer also configured with "read_committed" mode? Was the any failure in the downstream consumer (note, if the downstream consumer fails, it might re-read the same committed message twice -- neither eos_v2 nor "read_committed" mode can prevent this).